# Computational complexity of resolution of singularities of varieties over fields with characteristic 0

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, computational-complexity, reference-request

What is  the computational complexity of resolution of singularities of varieties over fields with characteristics 0?

Comment: You can look at the paper by Bierstone, Grigoriev, Milman and Włodarczyk "Effective Hironaka resolution and its complexity" in Asian J. Math. 15 (2011), no. 2, 193–228. 